# logging the cypher query for spring neo4j

Tags: logging, neo4j, cypher

I tried to log the cypher query generated by the spring data neo4j by using the following log4j configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.category.org.springframework.data.neo4j=DEBUG
```

However, I couldn't see there are cypher queries shown in the log. Anyone has ideas on the ways of investigating the cypher query generated for the spring neo4j data mapping?

Answer (score 7):

they are logged using `DEBUG`, you can set a logger for `org.springframework.data.neo4j` to see them.

Comment: Thanks Michael! I added that as the new edit above, but still couldn't see the cypher queries generated by the spring data binding. What I saw from the console is the logging about the internal works of the spring, defining beans etc, but not any clues about what the underlying cypher queries looks like.

Comment: can you share your log configuration?

Answer (score 7):

As of Sep-2019, I found that one of the answers in [Log cypher queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56126471/log-cypher-queries) was the approach needed (`logging.level.org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest=DEBUG`)

Answer (score 3):

Try using this :

```
log4j.category.org.springframework.data.neo4j=DEBUG

log4j.category.org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query=DEBUG`
```

Setup a DEBUG config and then try!

Answer (score 2):

With SDN 5.0.3.RELEASE and using Bolt driver, `org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest` logs the queries at `INFO` level. Using Embedded driver, `org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.request.EmbeddedRequest` at `DEBUG` level.

Comment: `org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest` also delivers at `DEBUG`

Answer (score 2):

For SDN Version 7 +, try;

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.neo4j=DEBUG
```