# how to disable log in spring data neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data

I am getting unwanted query log from spring neo4j like following

```
25-08-2018 23:47:07.597 [restartedMain] INFO  o.n.o.d.bolt.request.BoltRequest.executeRequest - 
Request: MATCH (n:`OntoCategory`) WHERE n.`name` = { `name_0` } WITH n RETURN n,[ [ (n)-[r_h1:`HasSynonym`]->(o1:`OntoSynonyms`) | [ r_h1, o1 ] ] ], ID(n) with params {name_0=Breakfast Items}
25-08-2018 23:47:07.610 [restartedMain] INFO  o.n.o.d.bolt.request.BoltRequest.executeRequest -
```

I am using following logging properties in my application.properties

Is there anything I've missed to add. I'm using spring boot version 2.0.3

```
logging.level.root=info
logging.path=path
logging.file=${logging.path}/log.log
logging.pattern.file=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n
logging.pattern.console=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M - %n%highlight%msg%n
```

Following two log properties are added from following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050366/logging-the-cypher-query-for-spring-neo4j) which doesn't change anything

```
log4j.category.org.springframework.data.neo4j=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query=DEBUG`
```

Answer (score 3):

The logging of the cypher query is done by `BoltRequest` class in neo4j-ogm. So that's where you should be changing the logging level like the following (to keep other logging configuration unaffected):

```
logging.level.org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest=WARN
```

Note, however that, as the logging level in this class has been changed very recently according to your request (per [#530](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/530), by commit [f37a78e](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/commit/f37a78e1f5120a60be8995b93dbeb4dd5368bf38#diff-1061a8c5962749570f66db21a3bef870) - logging level of cypher queries downgraded to DEBUG), if you upgrade your SDN installation in your project, you may just be automatically getting rid of the query logs w/o making this adjustment to logging configuration

(I currently have `neo4g-ogm-bolt-driver-3.1.4.jar` in my project, and I don't get the queries logged).

Answer (score 2):

log4j.category.org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query=DEBUG

This entry in the log configuration, logs the query. To avoid logging query to the log files remove this entry.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have this configuration :

```
logging.level.root=info
```

The root log level will be info, but if another level is different, it will override it for this log.

So, to have the following behaviour :

- Neo4j log will be displayed if its level is WARN or higher (so, no request log)
- Every other log in your app will be displayed if its level is INFO or higher

What you want is to do this :

```
logging.level.root=info
log4j.category.org.springframework.data.neo4j=WARN
log4j.category.org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query=WARN
```

Answer (score 2):

By adding this line in application.properties queries is not logging in console.Its working

```
logging.level.org.neo4j.ogm.drivers=OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the [log4j log level](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_levels.htm) to `DEBUG`, then all log messages at `DEBUG` level and above (*which includes `INFO`*) will be logged.

To prevent `INFO` level messages from being logged, you should set the log level to `WARN` (or an even higher level).

Comment: It will jeopardize my own application log.

Comment: Your app's own log entries would not be logging to the "org.springframework.data.neo4j" or "org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query" categories, so there should be no problem (unless you want to see some of the DEBUG/INFO logging done on your behalf by the Spring library).