# IntelliJ Neo4j hide Cypher queries in the console

Tags: intellij-idea, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Is there any way to hide the Cypher queries from being written to the console log when using Spring Data Neo4j?

It's making it hard to track other log statements as I sometimes have several hundered queries generated by one function.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52019947/how-to-disable-log-in-spring-data-neo4j

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to disable log in spring data neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52019947/how-to-disable-log-in-spring-data-neo4j)