# Log cypher queries

Tags: java, java-8, spring-data-neo4j

Is there a way to log cypher queries that get generated when we use spring jpa inbuilt queries like findById!? I have a complex inbuilt query whose cypher I need to see

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some code that you have tried so that the community can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j provides the ability to log all executed queries.

Per https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/monitoring/logging/query-logging:

Neo4j can be configured to log queries executed in the database.

Query logging must be enabled by setting the dbms.logs.query.enabled parameter to true. The parameter dbms.logs.query.threshold determines the threshold for logging a query. If the execution of a query takes a longer time than this threshold, it will be logged. Setting dbms.logs.query.threshold to 0 will result in all queries being logged

Answer (score 5):

Using Spring Boot 2.1.5, I am able to log Spring Data Neo4j generated Cypher queries just by adding:

```
logging.level.org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest=DEBUG
```

to application.properties.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Your suggestion was the thing that caused the Cypher to appear in the log. 

None of these other things I had read about (possibly in ignorance) would make Cypher logs appear: (i) add a `logback.xml` file (ii) try an application.properties entry `log4j.category.org.springframework.data.neo4j=INFO` (iii) 
try an application properties entry `log4j.category.org.org.neo4j.ogm=INFO`