# Neo4j repeat relationship when connect new node to existing node

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have a list of `People` node and now I want to create a new `Movie` node that has `ACTED_IN` relationship with multiple `People`.

Here's my `People` entity:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Node("people")
public class People {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Property("name")
  String name;
  
  @Property("age")
  int age;
}
```

`Movie` entity:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Movie {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Relationship(type = "ACTED_IN")
  private Set<MovieActor> actors = new HashSet<>();
}
```

`MovieActor` relationship:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@RelationshipProperties
public class MovieActor{

  @RelationshipId
  private Long id;

  private String role;

  @TargetNode
  private People people;

  public MovieActor(String role, People people) {
    this.role = role;
    this.people = people;
  }
}
```

`MovieDTO`:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MovieDTO {
 List<MovieActorsDTO> actors;
}
```

`MovieActorsDTO`:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MovieActorsDTO {
  Long actorId;

  String role;
}
```

My logic in `Service` class:

```java
public Movie create(MovieDTO createDTO) {
 List<MovieActorsDTO> actors = createDTO.getActors();
 Movie movie = new Movie();
 movie.setActors(actors.stream().map(e -> new MovieActor(
                                             e.getRole(),
                                             peopleService.getById(e.getActorId())))
                                .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
 
 return movieRepo.save(movie);
}
```

I ran the above code and everything worked with no Exception thrown. However, when I passed 3 actors in a Movie, all the relations will connect to 1 of 3 Person

[image: Like this]

Instead, it should look like this

[image]

I debug the program and everything from entity and DTO seem right until after the `save` function called in service.

Any help will be much appreciate.

Comment: You might wanna try some of the options mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050366/logging-the-cypher-query-for-spring-neo4j. To get spring data neo4j, to log your generated query, and then check the parameters of your query

Comment: I cannot really say why you are facing this outcome and I might be very wrong, but by feeling is that the mixture of using `Set<MovieActor>` in the `Movie` class and having a `MovieActor` (with naturally has a generated id) in combination with the Lombok `@Data` annotation, is prone to create unexpected results. The equals/hashCode of the of the `MovieActor` changes on save because the id will get set. Try to change it into a `List` and see if the error still exists. Otherwise it would be helpful if you could share the example on GitHub or similar.

Comment: Yes this is in fact the problem. I eventually made it work by writing my own equals/hashCode because apparently  Lombok auto generated equals is wong lol